# Find $ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{[f(x+1)-f(x)]} $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality

I have that $f(x)=e^x-\ln(x+1)+2x-1 \quad \forall x > -1$, and I am asked to find that $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{[f(x+1)-f(x)]}$$
A way to approach this would be by using the mean value theorem. That way I would have that $\exists ξ \in R$ such that $f'(ξ)=\frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{x+1-x}$. Then however, I need an inequality for $f'$, so that way I can get to use the squeeze theorem. e.g.: On a similar question, I knew that $ |f'(x)| \leq 1$, so I easily got: $$ |f'(x)| \leq 1 \Rightarrow |\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}|\leq1 \Rightarrow \frac{|f(b)-f(a)|}{|b-a|} \leq 1 \Rightarrow -|b-a| \leq f(b)-f(a) \leq |b-a|$$ And then used the squeeze theorem. I don't think that can be implemented in this example since I don't thing there is an appropriate inequality to $f'$.Is there anything anybody can suggest? Thanks!!

Comment: use x->oo in f'(x), also I can not see why plugging in the functions,  does not help you?

Comment: @trula I thought of that actually, but: $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{f'(ξ)}$, so I thought that $f'(ξ)$ is just a number, that has nothing to do with $x \rightarrow \infty $, although it came from $(x, x+1)$ Is this wrong? Can you explain how you would do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compute
$$
f(x+1)-f(x)= e^{x+1}-e^x-\ln(x+2)+\ln(x+1)+2=\\
=e^x(e-1)+\ln\frac{x+1}{x+2}+2
$$
For $x\to \infty$ the logarithm tends to zero. The term $e^{x}(e-1)>e^x $ tends to $+\infty$, so that is the limit

Comment: Well, I made it more difficult than it was didn't I... Oh well, thank you!